# How to get an array of values from $entry

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

In Gravity Form's class `GF_Field_Checkbox` there is a method called `get_value_export()` that returns `implode( ', ', $selected )` for a bunch of elements created by `GFCommon::selection_display()`

The `class-gf-field-checkbox.php` code so you can see what I am referencing.

```php
    public function get_value_export( $entry, $input_id = '', $use_text = false, $is_csv = false ) {

        if ( empty( $input_id ) || absint( $input_id ) == $input_id ) {

            $selected = array();

            foreach ( $this->inputs as $input ) {

                $index = (string) $input['id'];

                if ( ! rgempty( $index, $entry ) ) {
                    $selected[] = GFCommon::selection_display( rgar( $entry, $index ), $this, rgar( $entry, 'currency' ), $use_text );
                }

            }

            return implode( ', ', $selected );
        ...
```

This is all well and good, however, the problem with this is that I'm exploding the values that are returned from this method.

`$answer = explode(', ', $field->get_value_export($entry));`

I do not want to do this as there exists an edge case where a potential `value` could have a comma which gets exploded. For example, say there is an option in my form like below

```
Label: Are you not entertained?
Value: 
 [x] Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
 [x] Duis blandit, risus vel rutrum suscipit
 [ ] Duis cursus ex risus
```

As you can see the first two selections are selected, and this will be picked up and will then be exploded as such

```
['Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet', 'consectetur adipiscing elit', 'Duis blandit', 'risus vel rutrum suscipit']
```

When it should have been exploded like this

```
['Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit', 'Duis blandit, risus vel rutrum suscipit']
```

What method exists in GFAPI, or custom code can I use that could resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Rochelle's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75276520/3612634) answer was useful in producing this solution. Instead of using `GF_Field_Checkbox`'s method, I've created my own function that will pull out the necessary values into an array, while effectively getting rid of the comma issue, due to using `explode()`

```php
function get_value_export($entry, $input_id)
{
    $items = array();
    foreach ($entry as $key => $value) {
        if ($value == "") continue;
        if (!is_numeric($key)) continue;
        if (absint($key) !== absint($input_id)) continue;

        $items[] = $value;
    }
    return $items;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve the checkbox values in the following way:

```
    $entry = GFAPI::get_entry( **entry id here** );//add your entry id in parenthesis
    $field_id = **add field number here**;
    $items = array(); 
    $field_keys = array_keys( $entry );
    foreach ( $field_keys as $input_id ) {
      if ( is_numeric( $input_id ) && absint( $input_id ) == $field_id ) {
        $value = rgar( $entry, $input_id );
        if ( "" !== $value ) $items[ $input_id ] = str_replace(",","&#44;",$value);
      }  
    }
    $answer = implode(",",$items);
```

Comment: the last part feels superfluous, as I do not want to implode everything back into a single string. I actually want each entry to be brought out into an array, and the items that have commas to be there own individual element in the array.